# Flashback query getting 'snapshot too old'

Tags: oracle

I have following query

```
SELECT * FROM tabis_nov_events 
  AS OF TIMESTAMP
   TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-19 10:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

Which selects the data but at some point gives error "snapshot too old. rollback segment number 5 with name '_SYSSMU5$' ". I want to retrieve data if possible otherwise just leave it. I tried with where clause like below to recover by chunk of primary key but gives me error every time when I use where clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tabis_nov_events 
  AS OF TIMESTAMP
   TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-08-19 10:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
     WHERE ta_eve_violation_num<'101100010'
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'I want to retrieve data if possible otherwise just leave it'. You want to get no data back rather than see the snapshot error? Are you getting the same error with the `where` clause, or something else? (Is your PK a number or a string - not sure why you have that value in quotes).

Comment: If I don't use where clause, it shows some data. I am using PLSQL Developer tool and there are so many records. By default, it shows me one page of data. If I fetch all page, after a while it gives me 'snapshot too old' error. So I though I can retrieve chunk of data with a unique key (a string) like from say 1000-2000 then 2001 to 3000 and so on. So I put the where clause.After putting where clause,it doesn't give me sql syntax error but gives me same 'snapshot too old' error. I want to retrieve those data which were showing at the first and Leave other data, If I can't.

Comment: I can recover partial data with rownum however for some rownum, it can't pull the data and throws the same error. So I have to manually change the rownum like rownum>5000 and rownum<10000 and see if it throws the error or nor. This may not be the way of doing but can't figure out anything else other than this.